# How to display data in two rows instead of the default one row using JQuery Datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables, rows, multiple-columns

Using datatable I am able to display all required information in a single row. 
Due to space constraints I wish to display one of the column (comment) under another column (name) in the same row

.

**Current:**

Row1 Column1 | Row1 column2 | Row1 column3

---

Row2 Column1 | Row2 column2 | Row2 column3

---

Row3 Column1 | Row3 column2 | Row3 column3

---

.

**Required:**

Row1 Column1 | Row1 column2

Row1 column3 |

---

Row2 Column1 | Row2 column2

Row2 column3 |

---

Row3 Column1 | Row3 column2

Row3 column3 |

---

Code

```
dishTable = $('#dishtable').dataTable({
             //"bJQueryUI": true,
//          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
//          "iDisplayLength": 7,
            "sScrollY": "80%",
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "bPaginate": false,
            "sAjaxSource": "amsrequestprocessor?action=amsretrieveorder&source=ams",

..........


"aoColumns": [
                          { "sTitle": "SNo", "sClass":"dish_ID",   "mDataProp": "sno" },
                          { "sTitle": "Name",  "sClass":"d_name", "mDataProp": "dishname" },
                          { "sTitle": "List-Price",  "sClass":"dish_per_price", "mDataProp": "price" },
                          { "sTitle": "Bill-Price",  "sClass":"dish_per_billprice", "mDataProp": "billprice" },
                          { "sTitle": "Qty", "sClass":"dish_qty",   "mDataProp": "qty" },
                          { "sTitle": "Total", "sClass":"dish_tot", "mDataProp": "total" },
                          { "sTitle": "Customization", "sClass":"dish_comment", "mDataProp": "comment" },
                          { "mDataProp": null,"sClass":"rowEdit","bSortable": false},
                          { "sClass":"rowDel", "mDataProp": null,"bSortable": false},
                          { "sClass":"rowId", "bSortable": false, "mDataProp": "id"}
                         ]      

        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
<table id="dishtable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="sno">SNo</th>
            <th class="d_name">Name</th>
            <th>List-Price</th>
            <th>Bill-Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <!-- <th>State</th>  -->
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Customizations</th>
            <th width=16px height=16px></th>
            <th width=16px height=16px></th>
            <th class="rowId"></th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: OK, so that's your table structure, now where's the javascript?

Comment: I have put the relevant datatables code above.. pls let me know if you need more information

Comment: Two rows from one is likely to give problems if the table is sorted; you would need to take tricky measures to keep each row-pair together. It would be a whole lot easier to keep each row as a single row - eg. with `column1String<br>column3String` in the first table cell of each row. This could be achieved server side, or client-side by processing the rows with eg. a `fnDrawCallback` or `fnRowCallback`.

Comment: Thanks @Beetroot-Beetroot I have managed to tweak my service to render appropriately than to find a way through JavaScript - As the solution seems to be complex and more demanding to make it work in all the browsers

Comment: takrishna, yes, although I'm a client-side person, that's exactly what I would do.

Answer (score -1):

By using colspan we can split the td and using width we can align the table..

```
 <table width="100%">
    <tr><td width="50%">td1</td><td width="50%">td2</td>
    <td colspan="2">td1&2</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: How could i apply this to a datatable ? (Datatable jquery plugin)

Comment: This is specifically asking about `Datatable` your solution would certainly not work, the correct answer may be found here though: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html